# gto changing the image as instigram in twitter after posting?

Tags: iphone

Am posting the image after changing it to instigram color.In the view the color is getting changed.but after posting when I chech it in my twitter it is showing the normal image without any change of color.Can any one guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the image whose data's been modified when you're applying the effects. You might be using UIImageView to hold the image on your view, now let's assume your UIImageView's object's name is imageView, so now you use imageView.image property when passing the image to the function which is posting image on twitter. You might be passing the original UIImage object which doesn't know about the changes you did recently.

Comment: Aslmkm Ahmed,I dont have any idea on Instagram.Can u guide me how to have the instagram in iphone.I have seen iphone hooks but am not getting anything.May i k ow the step b y step process of doing the instagram.

Comment: As i mentioned above that I have done the posting of image.Its not the thing I required.So can any one guide me.

Comment: @Sheik, sorry couldn't get you completely, INSTAGRAM is an iphone app which is available on app store for free, you can download it from there. This app allows you to add effects in your photo before uploading. maybe I was wrong but seeing the title I thought u're mentioning the instagram app

Comment: Sheik, Kindly give some specific question or put some code snippet, might we'd be able to help better after seeing it.